# DNS Portability with regards to LDAP/Kerberos

Tags: linux, domain-name-system, ldap, openldap, kerberos

How portable is a DNS server when it comes to LDAP, especially Kerberos which I am using for authentication? Meaning, how much do I have to change to use the same LDAP server with 2 different DNS servers as long as they use the same names & IP addresses, etc.? Specifically, I am using an LDAP server on Fedora & the DNS servers on Ubuntu, latest stable versions for each.

Comment: you might want to look at ipa. it does both in one easy to use package.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just make sure the same dns records exist (A, SRV if needed) and you'll be fine. A better option is to have one dns a slave of the other so you don't have to worry about the replication

Comment: I will probably not be able to have 2 servers. I know that's recommended, but this is a school project so it needs less. (In case you're worried about helping me with my homework, the teacher pretty much told us nothing.)

Comment: You are saying as long as the records are the same I should be fine? This is what I was hoping. How about on the LDAP side? Will I need to change anything?

Comment: nope. the ldap server is just an ldap server. the only time youll get into a mess is if you have multiple ldap servers and you want to contact them on one name (failing over if one breaks) and also use SSL. Otherwise you should be fine as long as your dns records on each dns server are the same. All dns does is convert the name to an IP.